# clicking on tableView row create a button with its label every time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have use a `UITextfield` as search bar.

[See this image to see what I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9A6S.png)

Not with multi selection on every click on tableView`` row.

```
self.searchText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_sortedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
self.tableView.hidden = YES;

[selectednames addObject:_searchText.text];

for (int i = 0; i < selectednames.count ; i++) {
    [self makeLabelsAndButtons:i];
}
```

in `didSelectRowatIndexpath` in `tableview`

Comment: Please explain more....

Comment: whenever i click on the UITableview row it would create a UILabel or button as shown in the picture but it would be one at the time.

Comment: Please describe all your needs and code what you have tried in question.

Comment: Actually your explanation is bit little for what you want ...Please describe so I can help you....